# equivalent of capture group for matched subdocument

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I have a Chats collection with a participants subdocument like so..

```
{ 
    _id: '1',
    participants: [ { _id: 'A', seen: false },  { _id: 'B', seen: false } ],
    messages: []
}
```

There are only 2 participants and one of them is the currentUser. I don't know which. Also, there is only ever one chat for any pair of users.

In order to find a chat I use both user ids. So a find query looks like this:

```
Chats.find( 
    {   $and: [ 
        { participants: {$elemMatch: {_id: otherUserId}}}, 
        { participants: {$elemMatch: {_id: currentUserId}}} 
    ]}
)
```

I'd like to allow the currentUser to update his own `seen` field in one update operation.

Currently I have to find the chat first, determine which index of the two users is the currentUser, then build a document to update that user and update it in a separate operation.

Is there something similar to a regex capture group so I can know the id of the element that matched currentUserId? Possibly like this.....

```
Chats.update(   {   $and: [ 
        { participants: {$elemMatch: {_id: otherUserId}}}, 
        { participants: capture({$elemMatch: {_id: currentUserId}})} 
    ]},  
    {   
        $set: {"participants.(capture[0]).seen": true}
    })
```

Or is there a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well this may not be a solution you're looking for but I thought I should suggest in case it helps.

```
Chats.update(   {   $and: [ 
    { participants: {$elemMatch: {_id: otherUserId}}}, 
    { participants: {$elemMatch: {_id: currentUserId}}} 
]},  
{   
    $set: {"participants.$.seen": true}
})
```

This will work for you because the $elemMatch stores the index of the matched array. As your anding the $eleMatch, it will store the index matched by the last $eleMatch which will be current user in your case. So, when you use the positional opertor, it will update the seen field for current user.

Comment: That's great - slightly odd, but it works! I wrote tests and they pass in both cases - whether currentUser is stored at 0 or 1.

Comment: This is an interesting approach, and works without `$elemMatch`.  Do you have a link to the docs on how the `$and` operator effects the `$` projection?

Comment: sorry I don't. It was trail and error kind of thing. I wish I had something to back that up and was the reason I was little reluctant to put this as an answer.

Comment: I can find this: `the positional $ operator acts as a placeholder for the first element that matches the query document`, but nothing on how it works with `$and`.  No worries, I learnt something!

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to easily update the 'seen' status would be to structure the data like this:

```
{
    _id: '1',
    participants: [ 'A', 'B'],
    seen: [],
    messages: []
```

}

Then you can update the 'A' has seen the message like this:

```
Chats.update(
  { $and: [ {participants: 'A'}, {participants: 'B'} ] },
  { $addToSet: { seen: 'A' } }
)
```

- [$elemMatch](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/#examples) is not required if you have only a single query
  condition inside it
- [$addToSet](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/) will only add 'A' if it does not
  already exist.

Comment: That's neat. And, when a new message arrives from 'B' I just $pull 'A' from seen? Thanks for the tip about $elemMatch. I had read that somewhere but figured the $and made it complicated enough to need the long version. Sorry I can only accept one answer.

Comment: Interestingly when I omit $elemMatch, the $ positional notation no longer works as described in @Veeram's answer. The find() still works however.

Comment: `Chats.update( { $and: [ { 'participants._id': 'B'}, { 'participants._id': 'A'} ]}, { $set: {"participants.$.seen": true} })`    This sets participant "A" 's seen property to true.